# How can I reduce the size of the shapes in visio?

Tags: database, database-design, visio

The title above is clearly a very basic question. My real question is how can I reduce the size of my shapes (I'm using Crow's Foot Database notion) without the padding messing with the alignment. I'm currently in the process of restructuring a database at my job and so I decided it would be best to have a visual presentation of how it will look like for my boss. This flowchart needs to be printable so all the entities and relations should fit on one page. Here's a what I have so far:
 [image]

Comment: Reduce the font size. Or adjust the screen / print scaling.

Comment: This may help: http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/visio-help/tips-for-hassle-free-printing-in-visio-HA001182254.aspx

Comment: Save yourself a whole heap of time and buy a decent data modelling tool, such as [DeZign for Databases](http://www.datanamic.com/dezign/), which allows you to reverse engineer your database and stop worrying about formatting a picture. :) I have no link with Datanamic other than being a satisfied customer.

Comment: Print scaling is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem, I can simply use print scaling which is an option located under the file tab under print. Thank you for the quick responses!